# Ejecutar FindVisualChildren varias veces en WPF

Tags: c#, xaml, wpf

Tengo un archivo de texto que contiene 10 palabras, una sola de ellas por línea. Mi intención es llamar cada línea, visualizar la palabra en un `Textbox` y extraer cada letra de la palabra y mezclarla con letras aleatorias, la idea es que el usuario mire la palabra y la forme utilizando cada botón con la letra correspondiente, así como se puede ver en la figura.

*Captura de pantalla:*
[image: captura de pantalla]

En esta imagen se puede ver, como los botones son configurados en el `xaml` sin ningún nombre especifico, y cuando se ejecuta el código, las letras son asignadas usando la función `FindVisualChildren` pero eso solo me funciona para la primera palabra del archivo.

¿Como puedo volver a ejecutar esta función varias veces?

---

Para ubicar las letras *(las correspondientes a la palabra, y las aleatorias)* dentro de los botones utilizo una función llamada `findvisualChildren` que se encarga de asignar a cada botón la letra que le corresponde y visualizarla como su contenido.

Este es el código:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

El siguiente paso es comprobar que la palabra que ha formado el usuario al hacer click en el botón corresponde a la palabra extraida, de modo que cuando toda la palabra este formada debe salir un `OK` y mostrar la siguiente palabra en el archivo, pero cuando eso pasa no puedo volver a  reasignar las nuevas letras, porque no puedo volver a llamar a la función que ya ha sido ejecutada.

No sé cómo hacer que esta función se ejecute `n` veces, si cuando lo pongo dentro de un `while` hasta que este no cumple la condición no se ve el resultado, por lo tanto solo puedo ver la última palabra del archivo.

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomendaría dos cosas:

**primero**: al iniciar la ventana (onload) llames al findvisualchildren y guardes la lista de botones en un List como variable global de la forma. para así ya tengas todos los botones en esa lista para que así solo tengas que ejecutar una vez el método findvisualchildren y evitar el problema que tienes.

**Segundo**: también al iniciar (onload) cargues el archivo de text para que lo tengas en memoria (en una variable tipo List por ejemplo) y no tengas que estar leyendo el archivo cada vez que se complete una frase.

espero sea de tu ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Yo agregaria una tercera opcion mucho mas simple, si los botones son siempre los mismos (OP no lo aclara) y no se van a mover ni nada, simplemente sabes los nombres de los mismos, con lo cual mantiene una lista de los nombres de los objectos y puede directamente acceder a ellos sin mas necesidad que andar recorriendo el arbol visual y haciendo comprobaciones de mas.